# AWS RDS to S3 Error. "The XML WAS NOT WELL FORMED"

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline, amazon-aurora

I am trying to migrate specific data from RDS(MYSQL) to S3 using AMAZON DATA PIPELINE. but i get the error

> "The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against
>   our published schema (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error
>   Code: Malformed XML"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEWCQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf1X4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of building a custom architecture, i used the RDS - S3 full copy template. that seems to eliminate the error. although not yet getting the data in the s3 bucket, but i can access the empty csv file.

Answer (score 2):

It might be caused by using invalid-XML-characters in some part of the S3 objects. See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/333 .

To dig deeper, please provide more information:

- Is this caused by an API call? If so what SDK do you use and what exactly is the call?
- Can you share the pipeline configuration?

Comment: I am using amazon data pipeline. I am not making direct API calls. i use copy activity to get data from sql data node and then push to amazon s3 bucket already created.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot where you get that error?
Please check for invalid-XML-characters in the S3 bucket.

Comment: i have attached the images for the s3 data node

Comment: Can you try changing the data format from S3 DataFormat to CSV or something else?

Comment: You can also try making sure the S3 path exists and is accessible. Try adding a slash in the end: s3://my-bucket/my-folder/

Comment: i have even made the bucket public and added the forward slash. same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to set LifecycleTransition properties Days and Storage Class.

```
LifecycleConfiguration newConfiguration = new LifecycleConfiguration
        {
            Rules = new List<LifecycleRule>
            {
                new LifecycleRule
                        {
                             Id = "some id here",
                             Filter = new LifecycleFilter()
                             {
                                 LifecycleFilterPredicate = new LifecyclePrefixPredicate()
                                 {
                                    
                                 }
                             },
                             Status = LifecycleRuleStatus.Enabled,
                             Transitions = new List<LifecycleTransition>
                             {
                                  new LifecycleTransition
                                  {
                                       Days = 0,
                                       StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Glacier
                                  }
                              },
                             Expiration = new LifecycleRuleExpiration()
                             {
                                   Days = 1
                             }
                        }
            }
        };
```